# How to create object in async and await function in Node js?

Tags: node.js, object, asynchronous, async-await, shopify-api-node

Hi i am creating a shopify api node js script which runs with **async** and **await**.Basically i am using this to fetch data form paginated page and i am getting the data properly in console log for each page. the issue is i am unable to make a array in which i get all the data in the end of function.

Here is the code

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const priceRule = "641166639179"
const totalresult = []
async  function  findCodeId(price_rule, url=null){
    //get(priceRuleId, id)
    let urlneww = url ? url : `https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/price_rules/${price_rule}/discount_codes.json`;

    await fetch(urlneww, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
        }
    })
        //.then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            let rrr = result.json() ;
            rrr.then((data)=>{
                totalresult.push(data)
                console.log(data)
            }).catch(error =>  error);
        if(result.headers.get('link').includes("next")){
        let str = result.headers.get('link');
        let arrStr = str.split('<').pop().split('>')[0]; // returns 'two'
        //console.log(arrStr);
            findCodeId(priceRule,arrStr); 
            //console.log(totalresult)
        }else{  
        }
        //return totalresult

    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

}

findCodeId(priceRule)
```

`i am trying to push the data in totalresult constant but it is not working`. Could you please suggest how can i do this `so that on each result it pushes the data in the totalresult  and at end of function i got all result data collected in totalresult.`

Comment: any async function can be called with await to get the result. so fetch with data can be done this way... `response = await fetch` then `data = await response.json()`. to catch errors, put the await statements in try catch block.

Comment: @gp. could you please edit above code as you suggested. I am not sure how to implement that, i am pretty new in node

Comment: this should help: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing promise/async-await style which is making it complex. Also you are not awaiting while recursively calling function. Try this

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const priceRule = "641166639179";
const totalresult = [];
async function findCodeId(price_rule, url = null) {
  try {
    // get(priceRuleId, id)
    const urlneww = url
      ? url
      : `https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/price_rules/${price_rule}/discount_codes.json`;

    const result = await fetch(urlneww, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
      }
    });
    const data = await result.json();
    totalresult.push(data);
    console.log(data);
    if (result.headers.get("link").includes("next")) {
      const str = result.headers.get("link");
      const arrStr = str
        .split("<")
        .pop()
        .split(">")[0]; // returns 'two'
      // console.log(arrStr);
      await findCodeId(priceRule, arrStr);
      // console.log(totalresult)
    } else {
     console.log(totalresult);
   }
  } catch (Err) {
    console.error(Err);
  }

}

findCodeId(priceRule);
```

Comment: Hi @Ashish thanks a lot  for the answer, i just tried it and it seems working, could you please let me know how can we  print the totalresult  one time after all recurrsions and it dont have repeat data.  thanks

Comment: @RohitGoel basically add a else and print it. If this has answered your question, feel free to mark it answer for other people's reference.